# How to hide browser's menu?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am developing an ASP.NET application for an online quiz test. The set of questions would be randomly selected from a pool of questions. The application works fine, but I want to hide the browser menu option (so that user cannot save or print the test) when the quiz page is shown. I do not want to open a new popup window. So how do I do this for the active window.

The application consists of around 5 web pages, and the test is on pages 3 and 4. So I want the menu to be hidden only on pages 3 and 4. Is this possible and how do I do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. You can only hide the menu bar in a popup window.

Either way, though, the user can always right-click and select Print, or use a shortcut like Ctrl + P. And even if you could hide the menu, they could just disable JavaScript. If they really want to print/save the quiz, you won't stop them. I suggest finding another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do what you are asking.

And remember that there are other ways to print than using the menu of the browser : `Ctrl+P` generally does that , it's also possible to "save the page" from the right-click menu or using `Ctrl+S` -- and, of course, there is always print-screen **;-)**

The best "protection" you can probably have is defining a correct license *(which means you might need a lawyer, to get something solid)*, that explicitly forbids re-distribution of questions : this way, your users can re-use the questions for them -- you cannot prevent that, anyway -- but can't re-distribute them.

Of course, this is probably only worth it if you are developping some quizz with questions that you are going to sell.

Comment: Ok Thanks to all for their help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once the page is rendered to the screen the ultimate control goes to the user. He can turn off javascript and do the necessary job or he can capture the page and so many ways.

Better not to try doing this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the data is in the user's computer he may access it in one way or another, and i'm not sure its worth the hassle.

If you want to deny printing, you may try using some special CSS media types (like definning some styles with `display:none` or `color:#fff`).

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp

But even like this the user might simply press PrntScr :)

You may also intercept ctrl+P keystrokes, by using an onKeyDown event on the whole HTML body and stop the bubling, but it may not work the same cross-browser.

You may also deny right-clicking on the page by handling the onContextMenu event ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536914%28VS.85%29.aspx )

Also, the questions should be rendered as images, or deny selecting text from the page so the user wont be able to copy/paste the questions in an email (http://www.dhtmlcentral.com/forums//archive/index.php/t-18008.html mmight help)